# How to combine two programs into a single one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to find the average of how many seconds it takes for 1000 horses. I figured out how to find find the average of 1000 random integers and the time for one horse to finish. I do not understand how to implement them together.

**EDIT: Any advice to make my code neater is fine!**

**EDIT 2: Sorry it probably wasn't clear. Part A was to find the average of 1000 random integers from ranges 10-20 which should be around 15. Part B is to see how many seconds it takes for one horse to finish a race which averages out to 450-500 something. Part C is supposed to simulate 1000 races but find also find the average. ***

Here are my codes:

```
#Main Program
#This program will find the average of 1000 random numbers.
from random import randrange

def main():
  numbers = []
  for count in range(1000):
     number = random.randrange(10,21)
     numbers.append(number)
  print('{} is the average of 1000 random numbers from the range 10 to 20.'.format(sum(numbers)/len(numbers)))

main()

#Part B
#This program will similate one horse race.
from random import randrange

def race():
 goal = 10560 #2 miles is 10,560 feet
 current_position = 0
 elapsed_seconds = 0
 while current_position <= goal:
  elapsed_seconds += 1
  current_position += randrange(4,41)
print('{} seconds for one horse to finish the race.'.format(elapsed_seconds))

race()

#Part C
#This program will find the average of 1000 horse races.
def races():
 numbers = []
 goal = 10560
 current_position = 0
 elapsed_seconds = 0
```

Comment: Why not call race() from inside main() instead of random?

Comment: Make functions which take some arguments and return some results. Then you can combine your functions, because you can take their return values. Here, `race` should return the number of seconds.

Comment: @ai-le         any specific reason or logic , in Part a of code that the number has to be a random integer between 10,21 . similarly in part b the reason for  the random integer between 4,41.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not following your program completely, but I have a few thoughts.

One thing you probably need to do is imbed the race() module within races(), so that when you call races() is executes race(). To get the data sent back to the races() module, replace the print() function with a return function (keep and mind that return functions terminate loops), and put something like the following code into races():

```
race_value = race()
numbers.append(race_value)
```

Comment: `return` is not a function.

Comment: Sorry it probably wasn't clear. Part A was to find the average of 100 random integers from ranges 10-20 which should be around 15. Part B is to see how many seconds it takes for one horse to finish a race which averages out to 450-500 something. Part C is supposed to simulate 1000 races but find also find the average. (gonna edit post now)